# Java Regex, All ASCII Except \r and \n

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to check whether or not a string contains valid ASCII characters excluding `\r` and `\n`. I have `\p{ASCII}+` as the regular expression for valid ASCII, and I have tried `[\p{ASCII}+&&[^\n\r]]`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `&&` does not mean "and" in regular expressions.

Comment: @PM77-1: In Java it does.  More precisely, `[\p{ASCII}&&[^\n\r]]` is the intersection of the two sets, all ASCII characters and all characters that are not linefeed or carriage return.  Java implemented it first, but it's now part of the Unicode standard, and I've seen it in one or two other flavors.

Comment: @OP, your regex should work.  If you're validating, the plus sign should be outside the brackets (where you have it, it's a literal plus sign), and the match has to be anchored.  (If you're not using the `matches()` method, you need to add anchors to the regex itself: `^[\p{ASCII}&&[^\n\r]]+$`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can express your desired set as `[\x00-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x7F]`, which is logically the set `[\x00-\x7F]` without newline (`\x0A`) and carriage return (`\x0D`).

Since Java supports character set subtraction though, you could also try `[\x00-\x7F&&[^\x0A\x0D]]`